# Can't call array using methods?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, nullpointerexception

I'm a Java beginner using DrJava with the JDK 8.0 compiler and I'm writing a simple code that creates an array one class and calls for its length on another. I've reviewed the many threads about arrays, but I can't seem to find out why my code keeps breaking.

I wrote a version of my same code that works using one class. However, when I try to run it using two classes, it breaks:

Here's my one-class code:

```
public class SingleClass
{
  int array[];

  public SingleClass()
  {
    array = new int[5];
    System.out.println("Array Length: "+returnArrayLength());
  }

  public int returnArrayLength()
  {
    return array.length; 
  }

  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
  SingleClass one = new SingleClass();
  }
}
```

When I run it, it works:

```
>run SingleClass
Array Length: 5
```

easy.

But then my two-class code (The one I want) doesn't work.

Here are my two classes:

```
public class Array
{
  int array[];

  public Array()
  {
    array = new int[5];
  }

  public int arrayLength()
  {
    return array.length;
  }
}
```

And the other one:

```
public class Test
{
  Array testArray;

  public Test()
  {
    returnArrayLength();
  }

  public void returnArrayLength()
  {
    System.out.println("array length: "+testArray.arrayLength()); 
  }

  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
    Array testArray = new Array();
    new Test();
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get a nullpointer error:

```
>run Test

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.returnArrayLength(Test.java:12)
    at Test.<init>(Test.java:7)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I tried to make the syntaxis to be exactly the same, and DrJava thinks it's okay, but for some reason I can't run this code.

What might be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Array` object `testArray` in your `Test` class is not the same as the `Array` object `testArray` that you create in your main method. Your `Array` in your `Test` class never gets initialized which is why you get that exception.

You should pass in the `testArray` that is in your main method into the constructor of `Test` like so.

```
Array testArray = new Array();
new Test(testArray);
```

Now you should change your constructor in `Test` to the following:

```
public Test(Array array)
{
    testArray = array;
    returnArrayLength();
}
```

Now your `Test` class accepts an `Array` as a constructor argument, and it initializes it so that you can use it in your `Test` class.

Comment: Good suggestion. `testArray` can also be made `private final`. Then the compiler would have complained about the lack of initialization.

Comment: No problem. While learning by programming yourself is definitely beneficial, I'd suggest you read through a book such as _Java: A Beginner's Guide_. That will help you nail the basics of Java and make stuff like this a breeze!

Answer (score 0):

You have both an instance variable and a local variable called `testArray`. Only the local variable is initialized.